# Schwarzschild metric

Tags: general-relativity

Why, if the Schwarzschild metric is a vacuum solution ($T_{\mu\nu}=0$) , do textbooks state that $T=\rho c^{2}$  when approximating Poisson's Equation from the Einstein Field Equations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a coordinate slicing known as the Kerr-Schild coordinate system where one can look at the Hamiltonian constraint $16\pi \rho = {}^{3}R - K^{ab}K_{ab} + K^{2}$, and find that the left hand side has the same singularity that you would find in $\nabla \cdot E = \rho$ when you put in the $E$ for a point charge.

So, you can interpret the Schwarzschild solution as having a delta function matter distribution.  (though there are problems with this interpretation, too, and it's not something one should take **too** seriously)

Comment: This is full of formulas and nonsense. There is no sense in which the part near the central singularity can be interpreted as a delta-function point source for matter, not in any formalism.

Comment: @Ron: Do you want me to walk you through the integral?  There is a $\nabla^{2}\left(\frac{M}{r}\right)$ term in ${}^{3}R$ that shows up clear as day.

Comment: Yes, I want you to walk me through it, because you are wrong. Spacelike surfaces which define the three-manifold in the Schwarschild metric don't include the singularity, and $^3R$ is not divergent there. If you slice the Schwarschild metric at constant "t", t is spacelike on the interior, and there is no way for the putative source at r=0 to propagate the gravity out. If you deform the Schwarschild with a tiny charge, to resolve the singularity, the divergence at the center changes. THere is no sense in which your calculation is right, not even approximately.

Comment: @Ron: First, I did make a mistake in my first statement.  The slicing is done using Kerr coordinates, not Schwarzschild coordinates, so the spacelike/timelike issue is resolved that way, as Kerr coordiantes are timelike all the way to $r=0$.  If you do this, you will find that ${}^{3}\gamma_{ab}={\rm diag}(1+\frac{2M}{r},r^{2},r^{2}\sin^{2}\theta)$.  And, in this system ${}^{3}\gamma_{ab}$ totally does contain a $r=0$ divergence that formally looks identical to the $r=0$ divergence from a point charge.  I don't have the time to TeX up the full thing right now, but that's the outline.

Comment: Sorry to make you flip out with my simple mistake about the slicing.  I almost never use the straight Schwarzschild coordinates when doing 3+1 stuff anymore, thanks to the horizon singularity.

Comment: @Jerry--- "Kerr coordinates" are not what these are called, I don't know the right name either. I wasn't flipping out over your coordinates, but over your idea that the curvature can be considered as leaking out of the singularity like a charge leaks out of a source. The coordinate r is not timelike anymore on your 3+1 slicing, but the evolution direction is still not static, so the solution still cannot be interpreted as analogous to the solution of Laplace equation with a delta-source. This is not a coordinate issue.

Comment: I want to get rid of my downvote, because this answer is actually pretty reasonable, given that you choose this slicing, but you should say that in the answer. I wonder, what is the best way to understand this in a coordinate free way? The charged black hole "Kerr coordinates" would be instructive too.

Comment: @Ron: the coordinate system where the metric is written as $\eta_{ab}+k_{a}k_{b}$ is most assuredly called the "Kerr-Schild" coordinate system".  And there's not even an analogue to a static coordinate system in electromagnetism.  I said all along that it was an imperfect metaphor, and that the reasons were technical.  All I'm saying is that, in this coordinate system, $\int d^{3}x\sqrt{{}^{3}\gamma}{}^{3}R=M$.  That is certainly at least slightly analogous to $\int d^{3}x \nabla^{2}\phi = Q$.

Comment: @RonMaimon: I know that interesting things happen in the charged case when analyzing these things--in particular, there is a paper by arnowitt, deser and misner that looks at spherically symmetric collapse of charged dust in a 3+1 slicing of isotropic coordinates and finds that the electromagnetic self-energy divergence cancels the gravitational self-energy divergence to get a finite answer.  But I don't know a lot about the details of this work, either.

Answer (score 2):

Because the approximation for Poisson's equation is weak field. In order to get a self-sourcing gravitational field, like the Schwartschild solution, you need a region with a strong field. You can always imagine that the source for the Schwarschild solution is right on the event horizon of the black hole it describes.

Comment: @ Ron Maimon. Thanks, but what's the difference between a weak field and a self-sourcing field. It just seems odd that you can describe a weak field using two methods that are based on opposite assumptions. Please don't worry about making your explanation too simple.